# Floating header when using multiple stylesheets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question or two about floating headers.

Currently, I'm working with two CSS files, `bootstrap.min.css` and `main.css`, the latter being a custom file, containing the following

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#heading {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0; 
    background-color: #acc7dc; 
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed; 
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

which to the best of my understanding should start the heading block at the very top of the screen. However, sometimes when testing the HTML, there is a whitespace between the top of the screen and the header.

The HTML is structured like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" >
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Trial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="heading">
            <header>
                <h1>Trial</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't modify this behaviour anywhere else. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: setting `top: 0px !important;` for the header may not help, but maybe it is worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap you could utilize the `.navbar-fixed-top` class, that should correct for the gap . If you want to apply your own custom styes to the header, you would just need to apply both the class and the id styling:

```
<div class='navbar-fixed-top' id="heading">
    <header>
        <h1>Trial</h1>
    </header>
</div>
```